# What is the equivalent of "git status", "svn status", and "cvs status" for RCS?

Tags: version-control, rcs

Is there an RCS command similar to `git status`, `svn status`, and `cvs status` that can show the status of each file within a directory? For example, if a file has been modified since the last check-in, such a command should say that the file is "modified". In addition, it should show whether or not the file is locked (and locked by whom).

Comment: Consider converting your RCS repository into `git`

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but read about `rlog` command, it provides most (if not all) of the information. And then answer your own question with your findings and accept your own answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

[**`rlog`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/manual/rcs.html#rlog) gives a report that can be filtered, e.g., using a script to show which version of a file is locked, and by whom.

For instance, in this screenshot, **`rlog`** shows that I have a branch revision locked:

[image: screenshot using ded to show modifications]

It will not show when a file is modified, but it is possible to infer that, as I do in [**`checkup`**](https://invisible-island.net/ded/manpage/checkup.html) and [**`ded`**](https://invisible-island.net/ded/ded.html) using its timestamp:

```
$ checkup 2\>&1 |less
** path = .
   1:   ./
   2:   |-- MANIFEST (not archived)
   3:   |-- Makefile (not archived)
   4:   |-- Tekparse.cin (not archived)
   5:   |-- Tekparse.hin (not archived)
   6:   |-- Trace-child.out (not archived)
   7:   |-- Trace-parent.out (not archived)
   8:   |-- VTparse.cin (not archived)
   9:   |-- VTparse.hin (not archived)
  10:   |-- builtin_icons.h (not archived)
  11:   |-- charproc.c (newer than 1.1858.1.3, locked by tom)
  12:   |-- config.log (not archived)
  13:   |-- config.status (not archived)
```

though to be certain that it is modified, you would use [**`rcsdiff`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/manual/rcs.html#rcsdiff).  Though rcs supports branches (on files), rcsdiff does not automatically compare against the locked revision.  I use a script for that:

```
    $ rcsdiff -u charproc.c |diffstat; br-diff -u charproc.c |diffstat
    ===================================================================
    RCS file: RCS/charproc.c,v
    retrieving revision 1.1858
    diff -u -r1.1858 charproc.c
     charproc.c |   94 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------
     1 file changed, 68 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)
    ===================================================================
    RCS file: RCS/charproc.c,v
    retrieving revision 1.1858.1.3
    diff -u -r1.1858.1.3 charproc.c
     charproc.c |   20 +++++++++++++++++++-
     1 file changed, 19 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`rcsi`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160331000703/http://www.colinbrough.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/rcsi.README.html) to show the status of files within a directory. However, `rcsi` is no longer maintained.

[image: rcsi screenshot]

Alternatively, if you don't mind using a GUI, you could use [TkRev](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkcvs/) (formerly known as TkCVS).

[image: TkRev screenshot]

Comment: Good point with TkRev. It is available on many platforms, including FreeBSD: https://www.freshports.org/devel/tkcvs/